# I want to ask about web crawling through python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def laptopspec():
    url = "https://search.shopping.naver.com/search/all.nhn?origQuery=%EA%B2%8C%EC%9D%B4%EB%B0%8D%EB%85%B8%ED%8A%B8%EB%B6%81&pagingIndex=1&pagingSize=40&productSet=model&viewType=list&sort=rel&frm=NVSHPRC&query=%EA%B2%8C%EC%9D%B4%EB%B0%8D%EB%85%B8%ED%8A%B8%EB%B6%81"
    html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tags = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "ad _model_list _itemSection"})

for idx, tag in enumerate(tags):
    print(idx, tags)


laptopspec()
```

Through this code, I could get some information that I need. 
Now I want to get more specific information through some keywords like *GTX 1050*, and I want to print `URL` that contain that keyword. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def laptopspec():
    html = requests.get(url).text
    url = "https://search.shopping.naver.com/search/all.nhn?origQuery=%EA%B2%8C%EC%9D%B4%EB%B0%8D%EB%85%B8%ED%8A%B8%EB%B6%81&pagingIndex=1&pagingSize=40&productSet=model&viewType=list&sort=rel&frm=NVSHPRC&query=%EA%B2%8C%EC%9D%B4%EB%B0%8D%EB%85%B8%ED%8A%B8%EB%B6%81"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
GTX = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "img_area"})

for idx, tag in enumerate(tags):
    print(idx, GTX)

links = []
for link in GTX:
    if link.has_attr('gtx'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        print(links)
laptopspec()
```

That code looks for all of the divs with class "img_area" which is the one that contains the actual links, creates an empty list called links and then stores all the links that contain "GTX" inside that list.

Main problem with that webpage is that the links to the product and the description of the graphics card and other specs are stored in different classes. And the links in the class with the graphic information points to "#" which just refreshes the page.

Another way to do it is, if you know exactly which model you're looking for that has the card, instead of "gtx" you can do like

```
if link.has_attr('ASUS')
```

Or what ever you're actually looking for. Because that variable mostly just contains model number and link.

And it's only by chance that GTX is in the hashed link that this code actually works when looking for "GTX", so not guaranteed to find all of the ones you're looking for but every link I've checked out so far from this output contains a laptop with a GTX card. *shrug*

But hopefully this will get you in the right direction. I'm still new to Python but I was just doing a project in BeautifulSoup so I figured I'd try and help.